# Add sequential number in database, that resets every year

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am building a project using `Codeigniter` + `MySQL` + `Active Record`.

In my `MySQL` db i have a table named **Requests** with columns *protocol*,*year* and some other columns where i store general information of a request (like title, subject etc...), nothing special to mention.

Protocol and year are `TYPE INT` and must be auto generated like below.

Every year, at `01/01/XXXX-00:00:00` the `protocol` field must reset to number 1 (the first request saved after `01/01/XXXX`, must have protocol value 1) and for the upcoming requests, increase it sequentially by 1, until next year and so on.

To reset the protocol, i will add a cron in a later phase where i will do a trick to reset. Still don't know how.

> What i need to do now:

Whenever i add a new `request`, the `protocol` of the new row must be increased by 1.

Pseudocode:

```
new_protocol = previous_protocol + 1
```

> What i am doing so far

I have a function in my model which Inserts a new request, but so far i do nothing about the protocol number, i enter it manually through my form.

```
public function addRequest($request) {
    $this->db->insert('requests', $request);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() == 1)
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    return FALSE;
}
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

1. Should i find the last protocol number in my Controller -> add 1 -> send to model to add?
2. Should i find the LAST and MAX `protocol` number in model -> add 1 -> insert to db?
3. Something else?

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like you might be overthinking something here.  This is something that could get quite messy especially when taking leap years into account, so you need to ask yourself 2 questions.  Why do you need this, and is it really worth it?

Comment: That's the way the protocol works (where i live).

Comment: As for how to actually do it, I'd just create a DATE column, store the current date, and then DATE_FORMAT with %j to get the day of the year from 1-366

Comment: We don't care about the day. In a year you can create millions of protocols-requests and not 1 per day. The only restriction is that every year, i should reset to 1 and increase it again for as many requests as the users want.

Comment: I know this is a bit of a cheat, but if you used autoincrement as the field type which would automatically provide the next value bit, but at the start of each year, use `ALTER TABLE rableName AUTO_INCREMENT = value;` and with the value, set it to something like '2017000000'.  So the last 6 digits provides the sequence within the year.

Comment: Is it not derivable from an auto increment? The current number minus MAX(increment) from the year that is not the current one?  That way it's a display problem (assuming you never delete)

Comment: It should be auto increment: The current number PLUS MAX(increment) for current year. For the next year do the same, but start from 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i created a `library` in Codeigniter and wrote 2 functions, 1 in Library and 1 in Model.

> Library

```
public function getProtocolNumber() {
        $CI = &get_instance();
        $year = date('Y');
        $max_protocol = $CI->request_model->getYearsProtocol($year);
        $max_protocol = $max_protocol['max_protocol_number'];

        if ($max_protocol && !empty($max_protocol) && $max_protocol != NULL) {
            $protocol_number = (int) $max_protocol + 1;
        } else {
            $protocol_number = 1;
        }

        return $protocol_number;
    }
```

> Model

```
public function getYearsProtocol($year) {
        $qry = $this->db->select('MAX(protocol_number) as max_protocol_number')
                ->from('requests')
                ->where('protocol_year', $year)
                ->get();
        if ($qry->num_rows() > 0)
            return $qry->row_array();
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach like so:

1. add column ID in your table and set it to auto-increment
2. php - set the default timezone to use (since PHP 5.1): `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`
3. php - get current year: `$cyear=date("Y");`
4. get row `max(ID)` and compare if the stored year has changed compared to `$cyear`

if it has changed and following your pseudocode example:

```
new_protocol = 1
```

otherwise

```
new_protocol = previous_protocol + 1
```